# Is it possible to mount a subdirectory in ftp server via curlftpfs

Tags: mount, ftp

Currently I'm running this command:

```
curlftpfs user_name:password@hostname ~/mnt/sitename
```

It mounts the contents of main ftp dir on server to `~/mnt/sitename`. But on server I need to open `public_html` directory every time.

Is it possible to mount /public_html directory from server directly to the mountpoint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could specify the path on the FTP server after `hostname` part in the original command of `curlftpfs`.

For example, you could have your command as,

```
curlftpfs user_name:password@hostname:/var/www/public_html ~/mnt/sitename
```

**References**

- https://askubuntu.com/a/323215
- https://askubuntu.com/a/200812

Comment: I used: `@hostname:./public_html`

Comment: In v0.9.2, I neede to use : `@hostname://var/www/public_html` ! Made me a lot of time to find it. For some reason `@hostname:/var/www/public_html` didnt't worked, curlftpfs tried to go to `var` dir, that doesn't exists, and returned this incorrect error: `Error connecting to ftp: Server denied you to change to the given directory`